# How to pass the output of one echo to the input of another?

Tags: pipe, echo

I am trying the following

```
echo 5 | echo
```

but get nothing. What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commands such as `grep` and `awk` can accept the *[standard input](http://www.linfo.org/standard_input.html)* (STDIN) as a parameter, or argument by using a pipe. However, others such as `cp` and `echo` disregard the standard input stream and rely solely on the *arguments* found after the command.

Using the command [`xargs`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs) you can build and execute command lines from standard input, for example in your case:

`echo 5 | xargs echo`

There is not an exact rule to know if a command accepts the standard input, however you can have an slight notion using this two rules:

- If the command is used to somehow manipulate the content of a file (`grep`, `sed`, `awk` etc.), then it usually can take input from STDIN.
- If the command is used to manipulate the file itself (e.g. `mv`,`rm`, `cp`) or a process (e.g. `kill`, `lsof`) or to return information about something (e.g. `top`, `find`, `ps`) then it doesn't.